# Adding a new input parameter into pre-trained Artificial Neural Network model?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have trained RL Agent which uses DQN network to predict the best the action given the state.

- Neural Network used: ANN
- Input: State Vector (100)
- Output: Predict right action based on input state. (10)

This RL Agent is been trained and works fine.

**Problem: If suppose, tomorrow, 
    i have requirement which asks to add one more action into action space. (new action space = 11), 
    or even, asks to add a new feature set into the input state space (new input space = 101), 
    then is there way to use, previously trained model. Or would i have to train a new network again.**

Comment: Two things to notice: 1. You are not clear and you're question lacks a context. 2. You have not accepted any answer in your previous questions asked, so reward who helps you.

Comment: Just randomly putting comments doest get anyone any reward.

Comment: You've got 5 answers to your questions so far. If they did not help you, you should have acknowledged them by comments, providing more details why the answers were not helpful!
Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information about the SO community.

Comment: Ok, will make sure of it in future! Thanks!